# Hotkeys in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, user-interface, hotkeys, pysimplegui

I'd like to write a GUI with PySimpleGUI that can be used entirely by keyboard. Based on the following sample code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text("Hello from PySimpleGUI")], [sg.Button(button_text="OK")]]

window = sg.Window("Demo", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "OK" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

How can I add a hotkey which I can press using Alt+O to press the OK-Button? The O on the OK-Button should be underlined:

[image]

Comment: A high-level process for finding answers like this oneis shown in the PySimpleGUI GitHub issue checklist. 
 The PySimpleGUI Demo Programs is the starting point. Demo_Hotkey.py has what you need for the bind.  The underscore is an extension as found in the issues by u/Ohumeronen.

Comment: A PySimpleGUI application was released to PyPI a while back called `psghotkey` that can be pip installed.  It's what I use on my system.

Answer (score 3):

A minimalist working example derived from: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/4122

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Button("ok", size=(10, 2), key='button1'),
     sg.Button("exit", size=(10, 2), key='button2')],
]
window = sg.Window('Hotkeys', layout, use_default_focus=False, finalize=True)
button1, button2 = window['button1'], window['button2']

window.bind("<Alt_L><o>", "ALT-o")
window.bind("<Alt_L><x>", "ALT-x")

button1.Widget.configure(underline=0, takefocus=0)
button2.Widget.configure(underline=1, takefocus=0)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ("button1", "ALT-o"):
        print('OK')
    elif event in ("button2", "ALT-x"):
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: Your solution, the addition of the underline, inspired me to add the & character to Button text now like in Menus.